# gparted error: libparted error --- reached the end of the file during the reading of /dev/sdX

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, raid, mdadm

--- introduction ---

Hi,I am an Italian native speacker and so is my ubuntu, sorry for my bad English (I've spent a lot of money trying to improve it but :D, as you can see, it has been a bad investiment! :D )
The error description could be a little different from the one I've listed on the object (untranslated is "Errore libparted -- raggiunta la fine del file durante la lettura di /dev/sdX"). 
I am, also, a new linux user but, loving it, I decided to convert to ubuntu my home server (nas, plex, share, download, and so).

--- problem ---

I've got 3 HDs (WD RED 3.0TB). They was partitioned GPT and formatted as ext4. Then, I decided that, JBOD (linear) would be much better for my needs so I used MDADM to convert them. I made some mistakes and I've lost all the datas. I tryed to recover them but, after 2 days, i decided to use the backups to resume all. I haven't found any problem.
Now, The new Jbod 9TB partition works fine (again GPT - EXT4). I copied all my 6TB datas on it and i can read them back but, if i use GPARTED i got that error message.

It is shown three times, once for each disk so, i am quite sure it is not referred to a bad sectors or so. It is a logical problem but, due my lack of knowledge, i havn't been able to solve it, yet. Surfing on the internet i've found nothing. theoretically i could simply ignore that mistake but, as you can immagine, i would be worried to lose my partition just when i need it the most.

Thanks in advance :)

--- configuration ---

The nas config is the following:
CPU i3-2100t -MB zotac Z68itx RAM 8GB 
Disks:
Velociraptor 300GB with UBUNTU SERVER 16.04 XFCE (all Linux partitions are here)
3 WD RED in linear (JBOD) shared with samba (md127__sdd - sde - sdf)
2 (WD and Seagate) 1.5 TB in Raid 1 previously set up with MDADM (md0__sdb - sdc) and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a software RAID with mdadm using the "full" (/dev/sdX) device :

```
$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde 
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sde[4] sdd[2] sdc[1] sdb[0]
      31431168 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [UUU_]
      [===================>.]  recovery = 96.0% (10064540/10477056) finish=0.0min speed=205145K/sec
```

All devices in the RAID will **not** have a partition table. This will lead to the gparted error, because the libparted doesn't detected the software RAID header. The “reached end of file” means, that there was no partition table found on the specified device.

It is also possible to create a software RAID on devices with a partition table (/dev/sdX1) and identical partitions sizes:

```
$ mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

Then the gparted error message goes away. In any case, your data is save ;-)

### Update

Search for used partions on all hard disk with:

```
lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   200G  0 disk  
└─sda1   8:1    0   200G  0 part  
sdb      8:16   0    10G  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0    30G  0 raid5 
sdc      8:32   0    10G  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0    30G  0 raid5 
sdd      8:48   0    10G  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0    30G  0 raid5 
sde      8:64   0    10G  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0    30G  0 raid5
```

All your drives should be present here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply but it doesn't work. 

i wrote:
"$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md127 --level=linear /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf"
but it replies:"mdadm: no raid-device specified".

I've also tryed to write /dev/sdd1 and so, but nothing no changed.

Comment: @Falconfab Sorry, forgot the --raid-devices=4 option...

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. Now it says that 'cannot open /dev/sdd: device or resource busy'

Comment: use the `mount` command and check if /dev/sddX is used some were else. Be careful not to override a used device!

Comment: Ty, 
no, nothing uses it. The mistake occurs even if i write the string while the sdd is unmounted. I guess that is mdadm itself that uses the resources

Comment: @Falconfab see update. It is still very strange. If the device is not mounted, it sould not be busy. Also look at the output of `dmesg` if there are some message from the /dev/sdd.